# Vertically centering with absolute - no height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center a div `position: absolute;` inside its parent `position: relative`.

The css I am using:

```
#parent {
    position: relative
    height: 300px;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

The problem is that I have to set the `height` to `30%` to get it to center properly. However, when the content (mostly text) condenses on smaller screens it goes on multiple lines and the `30% height` screws up.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle for the same.

Comment: just want to understand, why you use a `position:absolute` for you child element ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hunt0194/j8xnm3n8/1/  ...  It's not shown, I am using a absolute position so that I can use skrollr position animation on the child

Comment: Try "#parent {height: 100%}". You cannot center anything if parent's height is unknown. Sometimes adding a border to the container make it easier to understand.

Comment: I edited my post, I did put a fixed height on the parent

Comment: @user3550879 So your title has nothing more to do with your question...

Comment: What I meant by no height is that the child has no defined height, so I can't use 30% or 50% height , cause they could end up being to big or to small

Comment: @user3550879 See https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/  And your question wasn't clear then.

Comment: I have used the technique before, but this should be simpler, I don' know why I can't figure it out. The parent has a defined height, the child does not.

Comment: @user3550879 In link, the `Harder: Unknown Child` part doesn't work for you? On modern browsers, you should use the flexbox model: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/centering_vertically_horizontally.htm

Comment: Having the extra pseudo element in the parent will screw up later functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check following which you want:

```css
#parent {position: relative; height:500px; border: 1px solid;}

#child {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin: auto;
 width:50%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        child <br/>child <br/>child <br/>child <br/>child <br/>child <br/>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where you see in question no height?

Comment: very close but it doesn't center the div, but it does center the TOP of the div

Comment: @ketan In title BUT OP edited question which is completly unrelevant now

Comment: It's not possible if parent have no height.

Comment: @ketan Using TABLE maybe

Comment: I apologize, there IS a defined height on the parent, I forgot to include it. (edited my post)  full detailed js fiddle here  jsfiddle.net/hunt0194/j8xnm3n8/1

Comment: In that case, this answer definitely solves the problem. @user3550879 I'm not sure why you think it doesn't.

Comment: Like I said it comes close, when I run your code snippet, It centres the top of the child div to the parent (currently on Safari)

Comment: @user3550879 child top border is `190px` from parent top border and bottom is `190px` from parent bottom border.

Comment: I apologize, It is a cross browser issue, it does work like you said on Firefox, not safari.

Comment: @user3550879 i guess you have to use vendor prefix for safari, try: `-webkit-transform: -webkit-translateY(-50%);` or ``-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);`` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing a responsive webpage I suggest you to use ***[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)***.

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
   #child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width:767px){
   #child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 10%; //desired height
}
}
```

Comment: my problem with that Is the child doesn't have a define height, I won't know what px/% to put

Answer (score 0):

do like this :assuming height is 300px

```
#parent { position:relative;}

#child{ position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%margin-left:-150px;margin-top:-150px;}
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to have negative margins if possible

Comment: My main issue is the height % of the child. It doesn't have a height

Comment: Then inspect and compute its height and apply the same, if it is a font then use font size as height and width

Comment: its not the size of the font, its the size of the screen, based on certain sizes the text may be on one line or 2, changing the height.